Will uninstalling git bash also uninstall my WSL git?
On my windows machine I have been using git bash in order to run git commands. However, today I had issues with large file names.
I therefore want to use WSL from now on, and I do not want to make the mistake of using git bash again.
Therefore I want to uninstall git bash from my windows machine. But now I am worried that uninstalling this will affect my current repositories and my WSL git installation.
Is this safe to uninstall?
Or are there other workarounds I could use to make sure I do not use git bash by accident in the future. (I rarely use my windows machine, and therefore I am likely to forget!)

No, uninstall git bash for windows doesn't affect git in WSL.
I use only GIT in WSL and it is isolated of windows, even I can't use git vscode functions, unless I open vscode with WSL connection.
Postdata:
Also, you must check your global git configuration in git bash if you want to import to wsl your global configuration. You can use: git config --list or look at your ~/.gitconfig file and check what you want to bring to git in wsl.
